# is oracle function compiled every time when called?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I read some time ago on a portal saying oracle function is compiled every time it is called , however when i tested it today it proved otherwise. I created a simple function like below

```
Create or replace function foo (p_in IN integer ) return integer
is
begin
  return p_in + 5;
end;
```

When i compiled it i noted down the value of below query

```
selectc last_ddl_time , timestamp from dba_objects where object_name = 'FOO';
```

i executed it several times and then again checked the output of above query which did not change.

So it seems like what i read earlier was not correct however i just want to confirm it.

Comment: No, you must unlearn what you had read and known till now.

Comment: Applause for challenging wisdom from portals and testing it yourself thoroughly. Nullius in verba!

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99899)

> Each subprogram is compiled and stored in executable form, which can be invoked repeatedly.

So the answer is: they are only compiled once (when you run the `CREATE` statement)

The same [is true](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS00902) for packages.

Comment: `they are only compiled once` isn't quite true; if the PL/SQL object is invalid, it will be automatically recompiled in the attempt to revalidate it when it is next referenced. As per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_dependencies.htm#ADFNS99985

Answer (score 0):

Oracle functions are certainly not compiled every time. That would be very inefficient.